# Strange behavior of Dispatch Group

Tags: ios, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch

I have experiencing very strange crash from iOS App. The function below is an implementation of some protocol so I cannot change its declaration to use some success/failure callback. It has input parameters and expects AVAsset at the output. My problem is during writing asset I get strange crash during leaving dispatch group (dg variable). I marked line of the crash with comment. This crash is not always happens. Just from time to time. This is the function:

```
func writeAsset(to url: URL, metadataArray: [AVTimedMetadataGroup]) -> AVAsset {
        let writer = try! AVAssetWriter(url: url, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie)
        writer.movieTimeScale = track.timeScale

        // setup writer, inputs and metadata adaptor and so on ...

        if writer.startWriting() {
            writer.startSession(atSourceTime: kCMTimeZero)
        }

        let writeQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "HH.Write.Track.Queue")

        let dg = DispatchGroup()
        var i = 0

        dg.enter() // Entering to the group
        writerMetadataIn.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: writeQueue) {
            while writerMetadataIn.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                //let group = ..fetch next group to write
                if i < metadataArray.count {
                    let group = metadataArray[i]
                    if writerMetadataAdaptor.append(group) {
                    }
                    i += 1
                } else {
                    writerMetadataIn.markAsFinished()
                    writer.finishWriting {
                        dg.leave() // CRASH IN THIS LINE
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        dg.wait()

        let writtenAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
        return writtenAsset
    }
```

Can somebody have idea what is the cause of this crash? I have only this information from crash report in xCode.

Comment: What's the crash detail ??

Comment: I dont have it. Just this line.

Comment: In terminal I have only this information: (lldb)

Comment: Can you set break on "All Exceptions", try to reproduce with that

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your issue is that since you are entering the dispatch group once, and then (sometimes) leaving it more than once inside the loop, that you do not have balanced calls. ie. you are calling leave more times than you have called enter.

Comment: How this is possible? The code can enter to else block only once because of the break instruction that terminates while.

Comment: I'm not certain this is the cause. Now I see it might not be because I see the break now.... however you may want to check you are properly following the standard pattern for using dispatch group. I see that you don't actually call leave as part of the completion for a dispatch queue block. I'm not clear what behavior you will get with the pattern you are using.

Comment: Does the crash happen every time the else is entered? Or only sometimes when the else is entered? I would test that first

Comment: Only sometimes very rarely.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution for the problem. It was not related to DispatchGroup but with AVAssetWriter and input array of AVTimedMetadataGroup elements. Each of this elements has time range. If start times for two of them is identical then writter during appending this groups is going to be in error state and behavior is very unpredictible. I don't know why error was in this line during leaving group but solution for me was to detect groups with the same start times and skip them.